# How to do a programmatically fuzzy search on pubchem using compound names

Tags: python, request, web-crawler, chemistry, pubchem

When I manually searched the pubchem web page using the keyword **"1-(2-Hydroxyphenyl)-2-phenyl ethanone"**, I got the following results.

[image]

Although no compounds exactly matched the above keywords, four compounds were found that partially matched the keywords.

But if I search using the following code, no compounds are found.

```py
import requests
prolog = "https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug"
a = requests.get(prolog + "/compound/name/1-(2-Hydroxyphenyl)-2-phenyl ethanone/json").json()
print(a)
```

output :

```
{'Fault': {'Code': 'PUGREST.NotFound', 'Message': 'No CID found', 'Details': ['No CID found that matches the given name']}}
```

Another example, using **methane** as a keyword

[image]

There is one **"BEST MATCH"** (compound 297) and other 444027 related compounds. But the above python code only gives me one result (compound 297)

Therefore, I presume that the above code will only get the BEST MATCH result. How can I get other related results by name please? (or the first few of the relevant compounds)

Answer (score 0):

Pubchem has a python API called [pubchempy](https://pubchempy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

It can be installed using pip: `pip install pubchempy`.

Using the API we can get similar compounds like this:

```
name = '1-(2-Hydroxyphenyl)-2-phenylethanone'

matches = pcp.get_compounds(name, 'name')
if matches:
  best_match = matches[0]
  similar_compounds = pcp.get_compounds(best_match.isomeric_smiles, 'smiles', searchtype='similarity',listkey_count=4)
  
  for c in similar_compounds:
    print(c.iupac_name)
```

This outputs:

```
1-(2-hydroxyphenyl)ethanone
1-(2-hydroxy-5-methylphenyl)ethanone
(4-hydroxyphenyl)-phenylmethanone
1-(2,5-dihydroxyphenyl)ethanone
```

**Note**: If you do not mention the `listkey_count=4` argument, it might take a very long time to make the search and may even return a `504: PUGREST.Timeout.`